# Can I schedule HTTP requests from Apache?

Tags: php, mysql, c, apache

I am trying to build a website from which a user can control some switches. The switches are on remote nodes (for simplicity the nodes can extract useful data from HTTP requests). The user may set schedule for when to turn on and turn off the switches. (e.g. turn it on at 4:00pm and off at 6:00pm on Tuesdays for an example).

Is it possible to send HTTP requests from my Wamp/Lamp system at specific times? (No page should be loaded in the browser)? So for my example, at 4:00pm on Tuesday, I will send an http request that will turn it on and at 6:00pm send another request to turn it off.

If not, what is the best way to handle such a scenario? A C program maybe?

The website is written primarily on php running over Apache web server. I am running on WAMP on windows or httpd (under Fedora Linux). Data is stored on MySQL database (that includes the schedule)

Thank you for your help :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `cron` and `curl`. `cron` can run commands at particular times, and `curl` can send HTTP requests. Your `crontab` might look like this:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
  0 16 *   *   tue   curl http://localhost/turn_on.php
  0 18 *   *   tue   curl http://localhost/turn_off.php
```

See `crontab(5)` for more information on the format and `crontab(1)` for more information on how to change it. (That's `man 5 crontab` and `man 1 crontab`, respectively.)

Answer (score 1):

When the time to send ON and OFF signal is fixed, just combination of **cron and curl** commands should be enough. Small googling on linux crontab should help.

It is bit complex when the time is varying (no constant interval). Then you might need a separate program (may be written in C) to get the ON/OFF time (say, from DB) then you could **'libcurl' C-library** to send the signal to HTTP server.